Ruby aws-sdk gem - how to list knowledge base sources?
I have several AWS Bedrock knowledge models. I know their IDs.
Looking to a way to read/work with KB sources - for example - run sync process.
Trying to use gem 'aws-sdk-bedrock' but it looks like it has no methods to read KBs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Bedrock/Client.html)? Any options how I can do it?
It looks like I have something related in Bedrock Agent - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/BedrockAgent.html but I don't have Agent and I don't want to use it :(

So yes, for some reason, AWS placed Bedrock`s functionality to BedrockAgent (for me - Agent is sounds like another part of Bedrock), so, it is enough to use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/BedrockAgent.html to get access to, for example, data sources
